# IOS, TableView, NSArray datasource - when to save?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray, writetofile

Newbie here :-)
Can anyone help me with a suggestion for the best time to write data in a UITableView/NSArray data source to a plist file?

I'm thinking of the TableView's life cycle. In a small list based, single view app, which would be the best view event to make a safe copy of the data in the NSArray?

I'm thinking the about the view's dealloc method, or the viewDidUnload method.

Am I way off??

Also, if this app had multiple views, using a tab controller or nav controller, should I handle it in the same way (each view for its self) ?

-Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewDidUnload is the right answer in all cases - do not do anything model related in dealloc.

If your view never unloads - you will have to adopt another method - either a timer or another event in your app - say save it every time a cell is edited.

As the iPhone uses a Flash disk, writing to files is quick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Johannes and Roger. Quick additional question: if I have a couple of lists in table views running under the control of a TabViewController, when my app is pushed out to the background, will iOS eventually dealloc any of the views or will they remain loaded as long as the app is not terminated?

Comment: yes, when you go to the background, your views are unloaded. The View controller will remain in memory unless you do something clever.